# Adding boolean field in JSONB

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to add a new bool field in my JSON object throught jsonb request but it doesn't work. How should I change the request?

```
update source_settings   
    set settings = settings - 'isEnabled'   ||
                   jsonb_build_object('isEnabled', settings->'isEnabled')   
where settings ? 'isEnabled';
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a valid Postgres error message nor does it tell us what happens and what you expected to happen. But the expression makes no sense to me. First you remove the key, then you add the key with the existing value.

Comment: The "isEnabled" field doesn't added

Comment: Could you help explaining how to add binary values via jsonb?

Comment: Well, your WHERE clause will only update rows that already contain the `isEnabled` key. If you want to add it when it's **not** there, you would need `where (not settings ? ...)`. And adding "binary" data is something completely different than "adding a boolean" value

Comment: `settings->'isEnabled'` doesn't really make sense as that will at best update it with the current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a *new* key then just append it using `||`

```
update source_settings   
    set settings = settings || jsonb_build_object('isEnabled', true)   
where not (settings ? 'isEnabled');
```

The WHERE clause will ensure that only rows are changed where the key does not exist. So rows where `settings`already contain `"isEnabled"` are not changed.

If the key doesn't exist, then using `settings->'isEnabled'` doesn't make sense as that will always return `null`